# How to catch the null constraint exception in plsql when inserting a record?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to check the null constraint of a column when inserting a record into a table. There, I am trying to insert a null value through a procedure to a column which cannot be null. Here is my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RecordInsert(s_id IN NUMBER, pid IN NUMBER, pr_id IN NUMBER, quantity NUMBER, rv DATE, exercise_num NUMBER)
IS
null_constraint  EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(null_constraint,-1451);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Supplier_Part_Project_Tab
  VALUES(s_id, pid, pr_id_, quantity, rv);
  dbms_output.put_line('The row successfully inserted');
  COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN null_constraint THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('The column cannot be NULL');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
      pkg_Error.prc_Exeception(exercise_num);
END;
```

This is how I executed the procedure.

```
BEGIN
 RecordInsert( 1002, '', 2001, 80, (TO_DATE('2003/05/03 09:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh12:mi:ss AM')),8);
COMMIT;
END;
```

In the above procedure, I am trying to insert pid as null. There, I want to fire the 'null_constraint' exception. But it fires the 'OTHERS' exception. Hope the oracle exception -1451 is correct for my requirement. But why does it not fire?

Comment: What do you get when added `dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm)` just after WHEN OTHERS THEN ?

Comment: Yes. It works... I have to change the oracle error to ' ORA-01400' too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id     NUMBER NOT NULL,
  4     name   VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
  5  );

Table created.
```

Procedure without exception handling section (to see what will happen):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RecordInsert (par_id    IN NUMBER,
  2                                            par_name  IN VARCHAR2)
  3  IS
  4     null_constraint  EXCEPTION;
  5     PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (null_constraint, -1451);
  6  BEGIN
  7     INSERT INTO test (id, name)
  8          VALUES (par_id, par_name);
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The row successfully inserted');
 11  /*
 12  EXCEPTION
 13     WHEN null_constraint
 14     THEN
 15        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The column cannot be NULL');
 16     WHEN OTHERS
 17     THEN
 18        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Others');
 19  */
 20  END;
 21  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec recordinsert(1, 'Littlefoot');
The row successfully inserted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec recordinsert(2, null);
BEGIN recordinsert(2, null); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."TEST"."NAME")
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.RECORDINSERT", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Aha. **ORA-01400** (not 1451). Let's modify the procedure, then:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RecordInsert (par_id    IN NUMBER,
  2                                            par_name  IN VARCHAR2)
  3  IS
  4     null_constraint  EXCEPTION;
  5     PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (null_constraint, -1400);
  6  BEGIN
  7     INSERT INTO test (id, name)
  8          VALUES (par_id, par_name);
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The row successfully inserted');
 11  EXCEPTION
 12     WHEN null_constraint
 13     THEN
 14        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The column cannot be NULL');
 15     WHEN OTHERS
 16     THEN
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Others');
 18  END;
 19  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> exec recordinsert(2, null);
The column cannot be NULL                  --> here's your exception

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Error code you used was

> ORA-01451: column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to NULL
>
> Cause: The column may already allow NULL values, the NOT NULL constraint is part of a primary key or check constraint, or an ALTER TABLE MODIFY statement attempted to change a column specification unnecessarily, from NULL to NULL.
>
> Action: If a primary key or check constraint is enforcing the NOT NULL constraint, then drop that constraint.

It is related to `ALTER TABLE` statement, not to inserts which try to insert `NULL` values into `NOT NULL` columns, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test (id number not null, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> alter table test modify name null;
alter table test modify name null
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01451: column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to NULL


SQL>
```